# Error generated by $ make conan_deps when installing Space Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, conan, sumo, proj

I am doing an installation of Space Veins.
And when I run $ make conan_deps as per the [Installation](https://sat.car2x.org/documentation/installation/) instructions, I get the following error.

The version of space veins is 0.2.
Other software versions are as follows
Ubuntu 20.04
Veins 5.1
OMNeT++ 5.6.2
SUMO 1.8.0
Conan 1.42.1 (A C/C++ package manager required to install PROJ 8.1.1)

> keita@keita:~/space_veins-space_Veins-0.2$ make conan_deps
> mkdir build && cd build && conan install --build=proj ..
> Configuration:
> [settings]
> arch=x86_64
> arch_build=x86_64
> build_type=Release
> compiler=gcc
> compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
> compiler.version=9
> os=Linux
> os_build=Linux
> [options]
> [build_requires]
> [env]
>
> ERROR: proj/8.1.1: Cannot load recipe.
> Error loading conanfile at '/home/keita/.conan/data/proj/8.1.1/*/*/export/conanfile.py': Unable to load conanfile in /home/keita/.conan/data/proj/8.1.1/*/*/export/conanfile.py
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
> module = _load(spec)
> File "", line 702, in _load
> File "", line 671, in *load_unlocked
> File "", line 848, in exec_module
> File "", line 219, in *call_with_frames_removed
> File "/home/keita/.conan/data/proj/8.1.1/*/*/export/conanfile.py", line 1, in 
> from conan import ConanFile
> ImportError: cannot import name 'ConanFile' from 'conan' (/home/keita/conan-1.42.1/conan/**init**.py)
>
> make: *** [Makefile:25: conan_deps] error 1

Answer (score 0):

The key is this line in the error:

> from conan import ConanFile ImportError: cannot import name 'ConanFile' from 'conan'

It means that the conanfile.py of the package being read contains a `from conan import ConanFile`. The `from conan` is Conan 1.X modernized version of the lagacy `from conans`. It has been available for a while in Conan 1.X version, if your current Conan version is too old, and it looks like it is, it will not be able to load that dependency `conanfile.py`.

TLDR: The Conan client version seems too old to load a modern recipe.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have to keep using an older version of conan due to other software dependencies, is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Use an old set of dependencies from ConanCenter. For that you should have captured a lockfile in the past, if you don't have that lockfile, then it is not possible. You might try to pin explicitly some older revisions like ``requires = "pkg/version#old_revision"``, but it is challenging to know which revision is the one that you need, and transitive dependencies will still be free.

Comment: Conan 1.X releases are forward compatible. You should be able to upgrade from Conan 1.42 to Conan 1.62 and things should keep working, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I updated to 1.62 and got the following error in $ make conan_deps.
Is this due to a spec change in 1.62 or is it universal across all versions of conan?


conanfile.txt: WARN:
************************************************
The 'make' generator is deprecated.
Please update your code and remove it.
*************************************************

Comment: That is not an error, just a warning that such generator is legacy and deprecated.

Comment: For more support-like discussion, it is better to use Github issues: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues